# ASP.NET MVC Default Project Structure and the Scripts Folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, project-structure

Is there any advantage to leaving the Scripts folder where it is in the default ASP.NET MVC Project structure.

In my mind it makes more sense to create subfolders for scripts, css files, and images under the Content folder.

Any downside to doing this?

Comment: [MVC Default Structure](http://getproductprice.com/Ads-define-mvc-project-structure.aspx)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596151/why-not-have-the-scripts-folder-inside-of-the-content-folder-for-asp-net-mvc-pro

Comment: Related post - [ASP.NET MVC (Domain Model, Repository, Fluent, Services - Structure for my Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1349640/465053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, no, there is no real downside to doing this.  It is how I have been structuring my MVC projects.

There are some advantages to doing this, actually... on many projects I am serving up all of the static content from a separate domain, so grouping all of the static content into a single folder has made the QA/production deployment process much easier (since we are scripting deployments with MSBuild and calling out to minify utilities for the CSS and Javascript files).

Comment: +1. Good point about the deploying static content to separate domain.

Answer (score 0):

Minor downside is having to look in multiple places for the 'bits' of each add-on framework etc. you may have.  Hence, I prefer \assets\ - then within each framework folder (jquery, bootstrap etc)  I have all the .JS & .CSS etc files and/or subfolders that come with that product.  However, MVC bundling helps by allowing you to have all your references in the one BundleConfig module/class if you wish.