# Why are static content and scripts in separate folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conventions

By default in ASP.NET MVC 3, you get a separate folder for `Content` (including CSS and images mainly) and `Scripts` (javascript).  Is there an advantage to this?

Comment: I don't think there is any advantage. It's just a semantic separation convention, probably just "cosmetic" though

Comment: It was already asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111303/asp-net-mvc-default-project-structure-and-the-scripts-folder
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596151/why-not-have-the-scripts-folder-inside-of-the-content-folder-for-asp-net-mvc-pro?rq=1